# Icon font display issue on phones

Tags: css, svg, icons

At work we're developing this component that displays icons next to links. The SVG icons are stored in an icon font (the WOFF2 format is being loaded). On desktop computers they look like they should however on both Android and iOS devices some icons look a bit weird. Some gaps are being "filled in" where they shouldn't.

The correct version of the icons:

[image: Correct version]

And here's how it looks on phones:

[image: Incorrect version]

Why does this happen?

It's not a media query issue, because it looks as it should when shrinking a browser window, but not in, say, the iOS simulator. It seems to be specific to mobile *devices*.

Comment: It might be an issue with the svg-files. If you look at the phone-icon its not filled in like the rest. I suggest you take a look at the vector-lines in the icons and see if the lines are connected. Just a spontaneous thought.

Comment: Yes, but it's weird that it's device-specific rather than screen-specific. Do mobile browsers render SVGs differently?

Answer (score 0):

This is the method with the deepest support possible right now:

```
 @font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
   url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
   url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
   url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
   url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
  }
```

[Have a look at this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/)  , hope it helps you.